# CSS select all child elements except first two and last two

Tags: css, css-selectors

I'm very curious (that's all) to see how you would select all children of an element except the first two and last two.

[I've a method](http://jsfiddle.net/rudiedirkx/7BQV8/), but it's nasty and unreadable. There must be a much clearer method that doesn't need 8 pseudo-selectors.

```
:not(:nth-child(1)):not(:nth-child(2)):not(:nth-last-child(1)):not(:nth-last-child(2)) {
    background: purple;
}
```

Yeah, that's pretty horrible. It literally selects all elements that are :not the first or second first or last. There must be a method that uses `2` as a semi-variable, instead of piling on pseudo-selectors.

[I thought of another one](http://jsfiddle.net/rudiedirkx/7BQV8/1/) (still messy):

```
:not(:nth-child(-1n+2)):not(:nth-last-child(-1n+2)) {
    background: purple;
}
```

Answer (score 88, accepted):

You don't even need `:not()`. `:nth-child(n+3):nth-last-child(n+3)` works fine.

Check it out [here](http://jsfiddle.net/7BQV8/172/).

Answer (score 31):

I don't see any other option than using `:nth-child` and `:not(:nth-last-child)`.

My version: `hr:nth-child(n+3):not(:nth-last-child(-n+2))`

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/7BQV8/6/)

According to `:nth-child` reference:

> The `:nth-child` CSS pseudo-class matches an element that has `an+b-1` siblings before it in the document tree, for a given positive or zero value for n, and has a parent element.
>
> In other words, this class matches all children whose index fall in the set `{ an + b; ∀n ∈ N }`.

So `nth-child(n+3)` matches all elements, starting from the third one.

`:nth-last-child` works similar, but from the end of element collection, so `:nth-last-child(-n+3)` matches only 2 elements starting from the end of collection. Because of `:not` these 2 elements are excluded from selector.

Comment: In my case (n+2) selects only first element. But (n+3) fix that.

Comment: Yeah, `n+2` will include the 2nd one. Just one `:not` and then a 2 and a 3, that looks weird =)

Comment: OK, I misunderstood the *first and last two* part of the question. Updated my answer and fiddle.

Comment: Yeah, yours is probably more readable than my double `:not` double `-n`.

Comment: You can invert the logic of either the first two or last two, or even both, so the following are all the same: `hr:nth-child(n+3):nth-last-child(n+3), hr:not(:nth-child(-n+2)):nth-last-child(n+3), hr:nth-child(n+3):not(:nth-last-child(-n+2)), hr:not(:nth-child(-n+2)):not(:nth-last-child(-n+2))`. The shortest and simplest is of course the first one.

Answer (score 3):

You could simply set your purple to all elements, and then remove it from the 3 unwanted ones:

```
element { background: purple }
element:first-child, element:nth-child(2), element:last-child, element:nth-last-child(2) {
   background: none; /* or whatever you want as background for those */
}
```

Thats imho much easier to read

Comment: Im sorry about that 3 elements instead of 4, read your question as " (first) and (last two)" instead of "(first and last) (two)". And you didn't say anything about having 6 properties. If your situation is too complicated for this, go ahead and use another answer. It's just another possibility and might work for some.